# How to build DB for each new user in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I'm building CRM as **SaaS**, so I need to understand the process to keep each new user's data private , Should I build DB for each new user? or create foreign key in each table to specify who is current user ?.

Please Explain how to implement that.

Thanks

Comment: DB for each user is not a good practice.

Comment: so what can I do ?

Comment: Keep user's data in a single table called `Users` and then use foreign key constraints to keep reference of their data.

Comment: @AlokPatel but it will be a huge DB in future !

Comment: That won't matter as database or your server architecture will help you to scale. But having different database for each user is a bad practice for single application.

Comment: One "huge" database, is far better than a "huge" number of databases

Comment: For a multi-tenant SaaS system, there are a couple of very well understood security mechanisms.  I am adding google searches to this comment for your review.  The first, which can be preposterously fine grained, is Access Control List, or ACL:  https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=access%20control%20list.  The second, Role-Based Access Control, or RBAC, is also useful:  https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=RBAC